# AsyncStorage.clear() is not cleaning the key

Tags: react-native, post, offline, asyncstorage

The user is filling out a form offline and sending it while still offline. When device is back online, I am trying to send that post, however, it is sending multiple times(older post requests which should have been cleared).
I think `asyncstorage.clear()` is not working, I have also treid `removeitem` or `multiremove`.

```
getData = async () => {

    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key')

        let valueParsed = JSON.parse(value);

        if (valueParsed != null) {

            fetch(this.state.url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
                },
                credentials: 'include',
                body: JSON.stringify(valueParsed)
            })

        }
        await AsyncStorage.clear();
    }
    catch (e) {
        // error reading value
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work :

```
await AsyncStorage.removeItem('key');
```

Comment: Like I said, it doesnt do anything differently. I have tried all of them. Moreover that when I use .clear() shouldnt this already remove everything everywhere?